# Pseudocode Python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

**How to make Pseudocode from my Code**
**Problem:**Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

**heres my code:**

```
def sum13(nums):
  while 13 in nums:
      del(nums[ nums.index(13): nums.index(13)+2])
  return (sum(nums))
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your pseudocode. What is your question?

Comment: how to make pseudocode and flowchart to my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `while` loop with an index instead so that the index can be incremented by 2 instead of one when an item of 13 is encountered:

```
def sum13(nums):
    s = i = 0
    while i < len(nums):
        n = nums[i]
        if n == 13:
            i += 2
            continue
        s += n
        i += 1
    return s
```

so that:

```
sum13([2,4,13,5,2,1,13])
```

returns: `9`

Comment: @yoltorresnewbie, Python is already so close to pseudocode – is there a particular reason you need this broken down further? Maybe it'll be useful for you to go through each line and write out what's happening in plain (non-computer) language.

Comment: Pseudocode is really about describing each step of the algorithm in a natural language with mathematical expressions so that it is readable to anyone without the knowledge of a specific programming language. You can therefore translate the above code into readable steps of descriptions in your own words, and that would qualify as pseudocode.

Comment: thanks I'll try ,, how about the flow chart for that?

Comment: @yoltorresnewbie Flowcharts are just like pseudocode, except it is represented as diagrams. Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart for typical flow chart symbols that can be used to represent the workflow of an algorithm.